# Gatsby Current Link Color

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, gatsby

I'm new to Gatsby, js and react but I'm trying to create a website to the best of my ability.  So far I've been able to figure most things out with a mixture of gatsby and css tutorials.  However, I'm stuck on one small change I'd like to make. I have a header on my website with navigation links that I added in with a ListLink

```
const ListLink = props =>
<li style={{ display: `inline-block`, marginRight: `1rem` }}>
    <Link to={props.to} style={{ fontSize: '17px', textTransform: 'uppercase', fontFamily: 'Roboto-Thin', textShadow: `none`, margin: "0", color: '#4a71b6', backgroundImage: `none`}}>
        {props.children}
    </Link>
</li>
```

I'd like to have the current link a different color, so if you're on the "Product" page, the link for "Product" is orange instead of blue.  I'm not sure how to implement this using the ListLink

Answer (score 2):

You can not add in-line styles directly to the React component. Gatsby's `<Link>` is actually `<a>`. One easy way to do it is to give a `className` to your "Product" page's component that contains your `<ListLink />`. So assuming your page's component's class name is `.product`, in your separate css you can style your links like:

```
  .product li a {
      font-zize: 17px; 
      text-transform: uppercase; 
      font-family: 'Roboto-Thin'; 
      text-shadow: none; 
      margin: 0; 
      color: #4a71b6; 
      backgroundImage: none;            
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `activeClassName` or `activeStyle` to the all the links and will get applied if it's the current page

```
 const ListLink = props =>
   <li style={{ display: `inline-block`, marginRight: `1rem` }}>
    <Link to={props.to} className="link" activeClassName="current">
      {props.children}
    </Link>
   </li>
```